# how to resolve argument not defined error?

Tags: python-3.x

i'm making a small project in python that is tic tac toe game but i'm facing a problem here is my code though it is incomplete
now my problem is while running my code , i'm getting error 'position' is not defined 
please solve my problem and thanks in advance !!

```
def display_board(testboard):
    print('   |   | ')
    print(' '+testboard[1]+' | '+testboard[2]+' | '+testboard[3])
    print('   |   | ')
    print('------------')
    print('   |   | ')
    print(' ' + testboard[4] + ' | ' + testboard[5] + ' | ' + 
    testboard[6])
    print('   |   | ')
    print('------------')
    print('   |   | ')
    print(' ' + testboard[7] + ' | ' + testboard[8] + ' | ' + 
    testboard[9])
    print('   |   | ')
def board_marker():
    marker = ' '
    while not (marker == 'X' or marker =='O' or marker == 'x' or marker 
    =='o'):
        marker = input('do you want x r o')
    if marker.upper() == 'X' :
        return ('X','O')
    else:
        return ('O','X')
def place_marker(board, position, marker):
    board[positon] = marker
test_board= ['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O']
place_marker(test_board, , '$')
display_board(test_board)
```

Comment: I'm getting `place_marker(test_board, , '$')
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: Because the position parameter cannot be empty @Armali

Comment: `place_marker(test_board, , '$')` - Your 2nd argument is empty, which is not allowed.

Comment: Have you tried checking why there is one variable called `position` and one called `positon`?

Comment: So why the have you posted the comment in the first place @Armali. I was just helping you out i wasn't pretending to be genius or something so just chill

Comment: @Chetan Vashisth - You were not helping _me_ out, since I wasn't in something. Why I posted the comment in the first place? Of course to inform the querist about his program's invalidity. For him, your first comment might have been of value.

Comment: Ok my bad !!! Sry @Armali.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
def display_board(testboard):
    print('   |   | ')
    print(' '+testboard[1]+' | '+testboard[2]+' | '+testboard[3])
    print('   |   | ')
    print('------------')
    print('   |   | ')
    print(' ' + testboard[4] + ' | ' + testboard[5] + ' | ' + 
    testboard[6])
    print('   |   | ')
    print('------------')
    print('   |   | ')
    print(' ' + testboard[7] + ' | ' + testboard[8] + ' | ' + 
    testboard[9])
    print('   |   | ')


def board_marker():
    marker = ' '
    while not (marker == 'X' or marker =='O' or marker == 'x' or marker =='o'):
        marker = input('do you want x r o')
    if marker.upper() == 'X' :
        return ('X','O')
    else:
        return ('O','X')
def place_marker(board, position, marker):
    board[position] = marker # make it position here from positon as Nicco Haase said
test_board= ['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O']
place_marker(test_board, 1, '$')  # pass a value for position too don't keep it empty
display_board(test_board)
```

**Hope this helps...
Thanks**